# oAuth Response from Reddit appends query params before '#' in angular app

Tags: angularjs, oauth, reddit

Reddit is placing the query params before the `#` in angular. Is this my fault or reddit's fault?
Whats a potential work around?

- On reddit, I have set my redirect url to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/#/oauth`
- When I go through the oAuth process I get a response that looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1:9000/?state=MY_STATE&code=MY_CODE#/oauth`

Comment: Your expectations are incorrect, I think.  According to RFC2396, Anything that follows # is a fragment that is not handled by the server or app receiving the request.  Presumably reddit does more than just a blind "string append" when they pass the values back to you - they append query parameters. These params rightly get inserted before the # fragment delimiter.

Comment: Thanks cheeso, can you think of a potential workaround to this? Without me having to enable html5 mode?

Comment: I don't know what "enable html5 mode" means, but...  you need server-side logic to handle the oauth callback.  You need a url that is accessible from reddit's servers. I presume that means 127.0.0.1 is not gonna work.  Also you need server-side logic that receives the request and does the right thing with it, whatever that "right thing" is for your app. You cannot do everything with angular and localhost.

Comment: I dont think this is required. Angular is fully capable of reciving a request, handling an oAuth callback and doing the right thing on the client side, at least as per my requirements. I was just wondering how I could get reddit to move the arguments after the #. More on html5 mode in angular [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to manually parse the contents of the url `http://127.0.0.1:9000/?state=MY_STATE&code=MY_CODE#/oauth` using some string manipulation.